# ImageView with no source does not honor layout, adding source does not repair layout

Tags: android, imageview

My base layout is a ListView of LinearLayouts, and each item in the grid is the FrameLayout below.  I am downloading an image to the ImageView.  Prior to the image being loaded, there is no content and the layout is shrunk to the height of the small ProgressBar (first problem), when I expect it to be 240dp or 120dp.  After the image is placed in the view, the layout does not adjust (second problem) and the height remains the shrunken dimension of a small ProgressBar.

loading image code:

```
@Override
public View getView(View convertView) {
    // ...
    // set up holder
    // ...
    new GetPhotoTask().execute(holder.my_tile_image, holder.my_loading, my_media_url);
    holder.my_tile_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.my_loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.my_tile_label.setText(activityObject1.track.name);
    // ...
}


private final class GetPhotoTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Drawable> {

    ImageView iv;
    ProgressBar pb;

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(Object... params) {
        iv = (ImageView) params[0];
        pb = (ProgressBar) params[1];
        return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), loadAsset(params[2]).media_url, true));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        iv.setImageDrawable(result);
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

the main xml:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="2dp" />
```

the xml for each row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_row_type_3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:weightSum="3" >
    <include layout="@layout/my_tile_layout"
        android:id="@+id/my_tile_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_row_type_2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2" >
        <include layout="@layout/my_tile_layout"
            android:id="@+id/my_tile_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <include layout="@layout/my_tile_layout"
            android:id="@+id/my_tile_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

the xml for row content:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_tile_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="2dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/foo" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/my_loading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_tile_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_title"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Why does the initial layout shrink to the height of progress bar even though I've hard coded 240dp for each row?  Why does setting a bitmap in the ImageView content not cause it to resize at that point either?  The first question most important, as I believe it will nullify the second.  Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**

To get the structure I want, I use RelativeLayout for the tiles (for layering ability), and for each row I am overriding the LinearLayout to enforce the sizing I want set for each row. As there is a potential for each tile's content to be larger or smaller than the view, this is screwing up my ability to rely on either centerCrop or fitCenter. So in my custom layout, I set the height to be proportional to the width of each row, and the mode of the MeasureSpec to be EXACTLY.

```
public final class MyRow3 extends LinearLayout { 
// ... 
@Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, makeMeasureSpec(getSize(widthMeasureSpec) * 2 / 3, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}
```

Comment: You will need to re-structure your frame layout. The dimensions are getting stuck because of : `Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top. The size of the FrameLayout is the size of its largest child (plus padding), visible or not (if the FrameLayout's parent permits). Views that are GONE are used for sizing only if setConsiderGoneChildrenWhenMeasuring() is set to true.` Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Comment: yes, but once a child (ImageView) is replaced with a larger item the FrameView does not adapt size. My ImageView is not GONE, it is merely INVISIBLE (to prevent seeing wrong content when rows are reused by the adapter). I may explore LinearLayout, but the overlapping nature of FrameLayout content is desirable for my_tile_label.

Comment: Egads! layout_height and layout_width are not even options for a FrameLayout.  I see your point explicitly now.

Comment: as @ashwini-bhangi pointed out, the FrameLayout is inappropriate for my purposes.  I wanted the layering ability of that view, but it sizes itself [based on the size of largest child][1].  When the ProgressBar is the only thing visible, that defines the size.  I don't know why it does not resize when the content changes, but am no longer using FrameLayout there.


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Comment: To get the structure I want, I use RelativeLayout for the tiles (for layering ability), and for each row I am overriding the LinearLayout to enforce the sizing I want set for each row.  As there is a potential for each tile's content to be larger or smaller than the view, this is screwing up my ability to rely on either centerCrop or fitCenter. So in my custom layout, I set the height to be proportional to the width of each row, and the mode of the MeasureSpec to be EXACTLY.

Comment: `public final class MyRow3 extends LinearLayout {
    // ...
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, makeMeasureSpec(getSize(widthMeasureSpec) * 2 / 3, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the structure I want, I use RelativeLayout for the tiles (for layering ability), and for each row I am overriding the LinearLayout to enforce the sizing I want set for each row. As there is a potential for each tile's content to be larger or smaller than the view, this is screwing up my ability to rely on either centerCrop or fitCenter. So in my custom layout, I set the height to be proportional to the width of each row, and the mode of the MeasureSpec to be EXACTLY.

```
public final class MyRow3 extends LinearLayout { 
// ... 
@Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, makeMeasureSpec(getSize(widthMeasureSpec) * 2 / 3, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it isn't honouring it but why not do something like this instead:

Set an absolute height in your ImageView to guarantee some space.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="###dp"
/>
```

Then change the layout back to an auto adjusted state just before the image is loaded:

```
iv.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ) );
```

Comment: hmm, I set the imageView to invisible in my adapter prior executing the AsyncTask, I was setting the ProgressBar to gone because I will not be using it again; changing that has no effect.  Adding some adapter code above, as well as the parent layout.  Sometimes while laying out, I see the intended layout display, then once the progress bars are loaded the tiles shrink down to match their size.  Strangely enough, if I set a padding on the ProgressBar element, the layout will stretch higher to accommodate the padding, and that layout persists

Comment: sorry my previous answer i realized was misleading as the imageview is special as the layout can't compute its dimensions until the image is actually set or loaded.  check my update, i was able to make it work in test where a value would leave a nice big space then adjust properly to fit when my image is loaded.

Comment: ah hah. So I cannot definitively construct an ImageView prior to image. Frustrating. Your solution does work, but seems hackish. My goal is to have the layout frozen and not resize ever. Regardless of the size of the downloaded image, I want my layout static. I have tried a FrameLayout with the downloaded image set as background, but found difficulties there with image stretching. ImageView seemed more appropriate to clip image into the allocated layout.

Comment: Got it, not sure if I'm making too much of an assumption but I found a huge speed difference in downloading the image to storage and then showing it rather than code I found to direct the download stream directly to the ImageView.  If you can get the download fast enough maybe the shift doesn't matter?  If not, I think you route of clipping is best.  Good luck!

Comment: hrm, I thought dealing with drawables was the quickest, so I just pipe the InputStream to a BitmapDrawable constructor. will explore.  Thanks!